# maven-compiler-plugin how to change the classes destination directory

Tags: maven

By default the maven compiler plugin put the compiled classes into `${project.build.directory}/classes`. I want to put them into `${project.build.directory}/myclasses`. The argument `-d` changes the destination of the compiled classes. I configured the plugin but I got an error: `javac: directory not found: C:\home\target/myclasses`.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.5</source>
        <target>1.5</target>
        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
        <compilerArguments>
            <d>${project.build.directory}/myclasses</d>
        </compilerArguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I was sure that someone would ask ;) I have to package several jars in one maven call using different classes so I need to compile part of the source in one folder and the other part in another folder.

Comment: @Sydney Maven deliberately makes such monstrosities hard. The best answer is to change your requirements :-)

Comment: Make separate projects out of it. If you boss said it to you just let him do the build. He has no knowledge of Maven. Sorry. Wrong way. Not the maven way. Keep you finger off maven.

Comment: @khmarbaise doh! thanks for forcing me into the right direction ;) I tried hard for a full day to configure Maven to run multiple different test suites in one module/project, when the obvious - to actually split the tests to different modules - is so easy!

Comment: You can keep the default location and package the multiple JARs with a include filter on package level (this is for example used to create -api.jar subsets). But avoiding this and using multiple modules is much better in the long run. The main reason for this is, that maven POMs not only are build instructions but also deployment meta-data. So it is better if each deploymnet unit has its own valid POM file.

Comment: AspectJ requires this - see: http://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/examples/weaveDirectories.html

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to do it like this:

```xml
<build>
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/myclasses</outputDirectory>
</build>
```

Answer (score 6):

The destination folder must exists. You can create it using a ant task:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>createClassesDir</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <mkdir dir="${project.build.directory}/myclasses" />
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: True, but if you are going to do that, you might as well run the compiler using ant as well.

Comment: Remember to delete it when doing `mvn clean`

Comment: `mvn clean` by default simply removes whole `${project.build.directory}`.